# RoomDB - Can you JOIN tables from different databases

Tags: android, android-room

I'd like to know if RoomDB supports a join from two tables from *different* databases.

Let's say I have the follow entities and databases:

```
@Entity
data class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey
    val fooId: Long,
    val barId: Long,
    val fooText: String
)

@Dao
interface FooDao {
    ....
}

@Database(
    entities = [Foo::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class FooDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun fooDao() : FooDao
}

val fooDatabase = Room
    .databaseBuilder(application, FooDatabase::class.java, "Foo.db")
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()

@Entity
data class Bar(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val barText: String
)

@Dao
interface BarDao {
    ....
}

@Database(
    entities = [Bar::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class BarDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun barDao() : BarDao
}

val barDatabase = Room
    .databaseBuilder(application, BarDatabase::class.java, "Bar.db")
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()

data class FooWithBar(
    @Embedded
    val foo: Foo,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "barId",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val bar: Bar
)
```

Is it possible to write a query where I can get the join model `FooWithBar` if the `Foo` table resides in a different database than the `Bar` table?

I know if I had both `Foo` and `Bar` entities in the same database, I could write a query in the dao like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM foo")
suspend fun getFooWithBar() : FooBar?
```

And the compiler, from the annotations, would generate a SQL query that would JOIN the 2 tables (`Foo` and `Bar` via the `Foo.barId -> Bar.id` relationship.

But I have no idea if it's possible to do such a join across tables in different db's.

I know if I host these tables in the same db I can achieve this, but I'd like to keep my db's seperate.

Does the fact I want to keep my db's seperate indicate a "smell"?

Does it depend on the domain model? If so, what are some good rules of thumb for when to split domain models into different db's?

Comment: In SQLite, you would use `ATTACH DATABASE` while connected to one database to "attach" the second database. You could then write queries with a database name prefix on tables to reference the second database. I have no idea if Room supports this. "Does the fact I want to keep my db's seperate indicate a "smell"?" -- IMHO, yes, insofar as you haven't really given a good reason for the extra complexity. There are scenarios I can think of where this might be valid (e.g., one database is read-only), but those would be exceptional cases, not the norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the fact I want to keep my db's seperate indicate a "smell"?

Yes, especially with Room. It introduces complexities and inefficiencies.

> Is it possible to write a query where I can get the join model FooWithBar if the Foo table resides in a different database than the Bar table?

For your simple example Yes but as can be seen from the example not with an actual SQL JOIN (without attaching), that is you get the Foo object and mimic the JOIN by then getting the appropriate Bar (or Bars).

If you tried to mix Entities from different Databases then you will encounter problems e.g.

even though there are no issues adding (whilst editing) a Dao such as :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.barId = bar.id")
fun getAllFooWithBar(): List<FooWithBar>
```

Which appears fine as per (screen shot from Android Studio) :-

[image]

When you compile you will get errors such as :-

```
E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO67981906KotlinRoomDate\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so67981906kotlinroomdate\FooDao.java:22: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: bar)
    public abstract void getAllFooWithBar();
                         ^E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO67981906KotlinRoomDate\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so67981906kotlinroomdate\FooDao.java:22: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (void).
    public abstract void getAllFooWithBar();
```

To get anything that requires tables from both databases in a single query will be outside of the scope of Room as each database only knows about it's own tables.

However, if you ATTACH one database to another you then will have both database in one BUT Room does not understand it. So you basically have to revert to using a SupportSQLiteDatabase (similar to using native Android SQlite (but with some limitations)).

**Example (very simple)**

**Foo** Entity

```
@Entity
data class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey
    val fooId: Long?,
    val barId: Long,
    val fooText: String
)
```

- Basically the same

**FooDao**

```
@Dao
interface FooDao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(foo: Foo): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo")
    fun getAllFoos(): List<Foo>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooId=:fooId")
    fun getFooById(fooId: Long): Foo

    /* !!!!NO GO!!!!
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.barId = bar.id")
    fun getAllFooWithBar(): List<FooWithBar>
     */
}
```

- Some simple Dao's

**FooDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Foo::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class FooDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun fooDao() : FooDao


    fun attachBar(context: Context): Boolean {
        var rv: Boolean = false
        if (instance != null) {
            val dbs = this.openHelper?.writableDatabase
            val barpath = context.getDatabasePath(BarDatabase.DBNAME)
            if (dbs != null) {
                dbs.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$barpath' AS $BAR_SCHEMA_NAME")
                rv = true
            }
        }
        return rv
    }

    fun closeInstance() {
        if(instance == null) return
        if (this.isOpen()) {
            this.close()
        }
        instance = null
    }

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: FooDatabase? = null
        fun getInstanceWithForceOption(context: Context, forceReopen: Boolean = false): FooDatabase {
            if (forceReopen) instance?.closeInstance()
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,FooDatabase::class.java, DBNAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(FOO_CALLBACK)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as FooDatabase
        }

        fun getInstance(context: Context): FooDatabase {
            return getInstanceWithForceOption(context, false)
        }

        val FOO_CALLBACK = object: RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
            }
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
            }
        }
        const val DBNAME: String = "foo.db"
        const val BAR_SCHEMA_NAME = "bar_schema"
    }
}
```

- CallBacks not used but ATTACH could be done in onOpen if ALWAYS access via attach

**Bar** Entity

```
@Entity
data class Bar(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?,
    val barText: String
)
```

- Basically the same

**BarDao**

```
@Dao
interface BarDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(bar: Bar): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM bar")
    fun getAllBars(): List<Bar>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE id=:id")
    fun getBarById(id: Long): Bar
}
```

**BarDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Bar::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class BarDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun barDao() : BarDao

    fun closeInstance() {
        if (this.isOpen()) {
            this.close()
        }
        instance = null
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: BarDatabase? = null
        fun getInstanceWithForceOption(context: Context, forceReopen: Boolean = false): BarDatabase {
            if (forceReopen) instance?.closeInstance()
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,BarDatabase::class.java, DBNAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(BAR_CALLBACK)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as BarDatabase
        }

        fun getInstance(context: Context): BarDatabase {
            return getInstanceWithForceOption(context, false)
        }

        val BAR_CALLBACK = object: RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
            }
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
            }
        }
        const val DBNAME: String = "bar.db"
    }
}
```

- Again CallBacks do nothing

**FooWithBar**

```
class FooWithBar {
    
    var foo: Foo
    var bar: Bar

    constructor(fooId: Long, fooDao: FooDao, barDao: BarDao) {
        this.foo = fooDao.getFooById(fooId)
        this.bar = barDao.getBarById(foo.barId)
    }
}
```

- As you cannot get both a Foo and a Bar this does the equivalent of a join by getting the Foo via the FooDatabase and then gets the associated Bar via the BarDatabase.

**MainActivity** putting it altogether :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var foodb: FooDatabase
    lateinit var fooDao: FooDao
    lateinit var bardb: BarDatabase
    lateinit var barDao: BarDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        foodb = FooDatabase.getInstance(this)
        fooDao = foodb.fooDao()
        bardb = BarDatabase.getInstance(this)
        barDao = bardb.barDao()

        /* Add some data */
        fooDao.insert(Foo(null,barDao.insert(Bar(null,"BAR1")),"FOO1"))
        barDao.insert(Bar(null,"BAR UNUSED"))
        fooDao.insert(Foo(null,barDao.insert(Bar(null,"BAR2")),"FOO2"))

        /* Get equivalent of join (simple) using the FooWithBar */
        val allFoosWithBars = mutableListOf<FooWithBar>()
        for(foo: Foo in fooDao.getAllFoos()) {
            allFoosWithBars.add(FooWithBar(foo.fooId!!,fooDao,barDao))
        }
        for(fwb: FooWithBar in allFoosWithBars) {
            Log.d("FOOBARINFO","Foo is ${fwb.foo.fooText} Bar is ${fwb.bar.barText}")
        }
        //* Done with the Bar database Room wise
        bardb.closeInstance()
        foodb.attachBar(this) //<<<<< ATTACHES the Bar database to the Foo

        /* Get a Supprort SQLite Database */
        var sdb = foodb.openHelper.writableDatabase

        /* Query Foo and the attached Bar */
        var csr = sdb.query("SELECT * FROM foo JOIN ${FooDatabase.BAR_SCHEMA_NAME}.bar ON foo.barId = ${FooDatabase.BAR_SCHEMA_NAME}.bar.id")
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr.close()
   }
}
```

**Result**

```
2021-06-16 16:35:04.045 D/FOOBARINFO: Foo is FOO1 Bar is BAR1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.045 D/FOOBARINFO: Foo is FOO2 Bar is BAR2




2021-06-16 16:35:04.092 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ee9871b
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out: 0 {
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    fooId=1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    barId=1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    fooText=FOO1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    id=1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    barText=BAR1
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out: }
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out: 1 {
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    fooId=2
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    barId=3
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    fooText=FOO2
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    id=3
2021-06-16 16:35:04.093 I/System.out:    barText=BAR2
2021-06-16 16:35:04.094 I/System.out: }
2021-06-16 16:35:04.094 I/System.out: <<<<<
```